# Why does VS Code's quick fix sometimes only show GitHub Copilot suggestions instead of the original C# suggestions?

Tags: github-copilot

I'm developing C# ASP.NET Core applications using Visual Studio Code, and my projects include ASP.NET Core 6.0 and ASP.NET Core 8.0. After installing the GitHub Copilot extension on my VS Code, I noticed that sometimes when I press Ctrl + . (or Command + . on macOS) to trigger the quick fix window in the VS Code editor, **it only displays "Fix with Copilot" without the original C# extension's modification suggestions.** This seems to happen in specific projects. I've tried disabling GitHub Copilot and restarting VS Code, but the problem persists. How can I fix this? Thank you.

---

Here is my Visual Studio version information:

Version: 1.87.2 (user setup)
Commit: 863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6
Date: 2024-03-08T15:20:17.278Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631

---

- Here are one of my ASP.NET Core 8.0 unit test project.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deSPL.png)
- This is another ASP.NET Core 6.0 project, the quick fix only display "Fix with Copilot"! Why there is no quick fix like above.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UioG5.png)